Error on file upload in Expo - React Native
I'm working on a native react application with Expo and users can upload images.
When I test the application on the local API everything goes fine, the upload is done but when I go online nothing works anymore and I get this error:
<title>Bad request</title>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand. </p>

I use: expo-image-picker to select images in the library
Here is the code for the submission function
const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<any> = async () => {
        try {
            if (photos.length > 0) {
                const session = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("session")
                const formData = new FormData()

                photos.forEach((image) => {
                    const uri =
                        Platform.OS === "ios" ? image.uri.replace("file://", "") : image.uri

                    formData.append("photos", {
                        uri: uri,
                        type: image.mimeType || "image/jpeg",
                        name: image.fileName || "photo.jpg",
                    } as any)
                })

                setIsLoading(true)
                const response = await fetch(
                    "https://api.gbhconsultingservice.com/setup/photos",
                    {
                        body: formData,
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: {
                            Authorization: `Bearer ${session}`,
                        },
                    }
                )

                if (response.ok) {
                    router.push("/(app)/user")
                }

                const result = await response.text()
                console.log("Success:", result)
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        } finally {
            setIsLoading(false)
        }
    }

I've hosted my API on PlanetHoster and to manage Nodejs applications they use Phusion Passenger.
I need help please
I was expecting the request to at least hit the endpoint but it doesn't even reach there
